# react-native TextInput displays wrong when changing height on Android

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

I have a TextInput with the following style:

```
amountInput: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
  color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
},
```

On iOS it correctly looks like it doesn't have enough padding:

[image]

On Android is has enormous padding by default:

[image]

Not a problem - I'll set a right and left padding, and a height:

```
amountInput: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
  height: 30,
  paddingRight: 5,
  paddingLeft: 5,
  color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
}
```

Looks good on iOS:

[image]

But Android messes up:

[image]

How can I make an Android input box like the penultimate iOS screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: just play with the `paddingVertical` , set it to `0` for example , and remove the `height`

Comment: Thanks that did it (paddingVertical 0 and removing height) - feel free to add it as an answer

Comment: done, glad it helped

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Android adds some default padding on top and bottom, you can reset them by adding `paddingVertical: 0` to your element' style.

Comment: It worked for me by adding `paddingTop: 0` and `paddingBottom: 0`. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

For me it was text alignment issue in Android. Adding `textAlignVertical: 'top'` to the style fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To make the text input look the same on both iOS and Android. Give it a specific height, this will override the default height in android.

Answer (score 0):

Add `paddingVertical: 0` and `paddingHorizontal: 0` on Android to fix this.