# React Native Text Input Has Hidden Padding On Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have the following code which is used to put a text label right next to a text input inline:

```
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text
        style={{ fontSize: 16, backgroundColor: "green" }}
      >
         +1{" "}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          fontSize: 16,
          backgroundColor: "red",
          flex: 1,
        }}
        placeholder="Enter your phone number"
      />
    </View>
```

[image]

As you can see, I put them in a flex row view, aligning them to the center. For some reason, on Android, you can see the text input has a larger height, despite having the same font size.

There seemed to be some kind of hidden padding so I tried adding `padding: 0` but that didn't work either. On iOS, they are the exact same height. Any idea of what I can do here?

To be clear, I want them to be the same height on Android as iOS correctly does. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may add `paddingVertical: 0` to style. This will reset the Android native module padding.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
  <Text
    style={{ fontSize: 16, backgroundColor: "green" }}
  >
     +1{" "}
  </Text>
  <TextInput
    style={{
      fontSize: 16,
      backgroundColor: "red",
      flex: 1,
      paddingVertical: 0
    }}
    placeholder="Enter your phone number"
  />
</View>
```

**Result**
[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882782/20002061

Comment: I tried adding both `padding: 0` and `paddingVertical: 0` to the `TextInput` component and the padding still exists unfortunately. Were you able to get it to work with that? Peter thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, I tried in my real Android device and it works.

Comment: Huh, weird. Just copied your code and it still didn't work. Maybe it has to do with the version of Android? I am running on a Moto G Power running Android version 11. 

This is my first time developing for Android devices. Is there really this kind of discrepencies between OS and device?

Thanks again Peter!

Comment: I am running on Sumsung Galaxy S10 with Android version 12. I have seen there are differences in functions but not UI layouts with different Android version. You may try the code in Android emulator which you can select specific Android version to see the issue still exist or not.